# why does ReactJS suppress changes in <input> elements but not in e.g. <select> elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's a SSCCE to illustrate my question:

```
const React = require('react');

const App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            text: 'foo',
            selection: 'apples'
        };
    }
    , render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>                
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.text}/>
                </div>
                <select>
                    <option value='bananas' selected={this.state.selection==='bananas'}>bananas</option>                
                    <option value='apples'  selected={this.state.selection==='apples'} >apples </option>                    
                    <option value='onions'  selected={this.state.selection==='onions'} >onions </option>                
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The above React component when rendered, displays (unsurprisingly) the below view:

[image]

The model is taken into account as expected.

When one tries to type into the `<input>` element nothing happens. The explanation is that ReactJS uses one way flow and you have to add `onchange` listeners to update the model etc. That's fine.

What I don't get is why ReactJS prevents the `<input>` element from changing and forces it to always reflect the model value that flowed down to it, whereas at the same time it allows me to change the `<select>` element:

[image]

[image]

Apparently my mental model is lacking. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a **controlled** `<input>` element and an **uncontrolled** `<select>` element. See [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Its possible to create an uncontrolled text input by not specifying the `value` prop.

And its possible to create a controlled `select` element by specifying the `value` prop.

```
<select value={this.state.value}>
  <option value="bannanas">bananas</option>
  <option value="apples">apples</option>
  <option value="onions">onions</option>
</select>
```

There is documentation explaining specifically this. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Comment: The page you linked describes the use of the `value` attribute in the `select` element (as opposed to the use of `selected` attributes in the `option` option elements) only in terms of it being "more convenient [..] because you only need to update it in one place". There is no explanation or indication of the fact suggested by your answer that hard-cording the `value` attribute in the `select` element creates a controlled component whereas hard-coding the `selected` attribute in an `option` element does not.

Answer (score 4):

You're hard coding the `value` to be `this.state.text` so it will always be the same on every keystroke. See the [forms documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: By the same rationale, I am also hard-coding the `selected` attribute in the `option` element. The page you linked contains a definition of controlled components only for `input` elements: `An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a "controlled component".` Should I understand from the above the the `value` attribute is special and when used in any component (not just `input`) makes it a "controlled" component? The wording is not very clear and is almost circular ("an element whose value is controlled by React is a controlled component")

Comment: The correct way in React to set a select's value is `<select value={}>`, not setting `selected` on an individual element